# LED blinking circuit design

Tags: led, flipflop, 555, latch

I am trying monitor activity on Rx/Tx lines of UART signals with led's. I have more number of channels(20) so i dont have place to use micro controller for this purpose.  NE556 timer in monostable mode also not an option because still i need 20 of those and space concerns. Trying to use NE555 timer in astable mode along with d-flip-flop to monitor activity with minimal components for this purpose.

I tried the below circuit and it works fine but Led's are blinking asynchronously and some times it misses to show the data with high baud rate at 115200.
[image]

Any suggestions on different approach or different designs with less number of components??

Comment: is it necessary to see 1 byte stetched out to 600ms for this?

Comment: What is your specification? Low on RX/TX pin will keep on a LED for low long? What is the baud rate?

Comment: You could simply use 1k to LED (10Cd type 5mm) or something like this http://tinyurl.com/yb25x24o

Comment: A single resistor and transistor per LED would do fine.

Comment: @Justme baud rate is 115200 as i mentioned above. I want to keep LED on for 5-10 ms.

Answer (score 3):

> Trying to use NE555 timer in astable mode along with d-flip-flop to monitor activity with minimal components for this purpose.

I count two different supplies, and ten components (aside from the LED and its series resistor). You forgot to add decoupling to your flipflop's and your 555's supply, too. A 50 ct microcontoller + one decoupling cap would do better than with 10 less components.

So, your NE555 approach seems the least space-saving you have come up with!

Microcontrollers with 20 GPIO inputs aren't rare. This can literally be solved with just two or maybe four components, for all twenty channels at once.